# Mismatch between A2P Compliance CSV and Regulatory / Messaging Service APIs

Tags: twilio, phone-number

The A2P Compliance Report and the Twilio Console have been showing mismatches in the status of a phone number for the past month or so.

I'll have a phone number that is compliant according to the Regulatory API:

[image: Compliant]

And successfully attached to a messaging service.

But In the Compliance Report I get a status of unregistered:

[image: Compliance Report]

Any Suggestion for how I can programmatically determine the real status of a phone number?

Will these phone numbers be blocked starting August 31?

I've tried to remove the number from the messaging service and add it back.

Answer (score 1):

Good luck getting an answer from Twilio.  They have created this mess...they created an artificial cut off date and then made the registration process a catastrophic and infinite loop of a clusterphuck.  We are on our 3rd application for our first registered campaign.  Each one has taken about 4 weeks to be reviewed and ultimately denied with the reason of "Its one of these 20 reasons" leaving you completely in the dark about what information needs correcting.  Their support is $hit....and I use $ because it costs money for nothing.  Come tonight at midnight, we are expecting a big impact to our operations - with zero recourse.  This IS Twilio's doing.

But the answer to your question is YES...it will be cut off.

You want a real answer from Twilio...you're gonna pay for it.  And then at best, your only going to get a vague answer that takes 50 emails just to get any clarification on their own responses and take 3 months to get through because they only respond to support queries about once every 3 to 4 days.

Excuse my french...but F*** Twilio.  I am moving my business away from them as fast as I can.